# How install AVIDEMUX on UBUNTU 17.10 (artful aardvark)?

Tags: ppa, 17.10, snap, avidemux, flatpak

How install AVIDEMUX on UBUNTU 17.10 (artful aardvark) ?

1. It is not available in Software Center
2. Not available in GETDEB.net repository
3. not available in unofficial PPA (Thanh Tung Nguyen), last builds are for 17.04

Can i use FLATPAK or SNAP packages ? Or how could I install it ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way that I have found to do this is download the source code, compile the packages and install. This [guide](http://avidemux.org/admWiki/doku.php?id=build:install_2.6) is pretty good.

Its worth reading bootstrap.bash to check the compile options. These sometimes change more regularly than the guide.

Once you have compiled the packages, you need to install them with `dpkg -i ...`

Comment: This does not answer OP question (..on artful 17.10)

Answer (score 0):

This link explain how to do it: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/08/install-avidemux-2-7-0-in-ubuntu-16-04-or-17-04/

Just run the commands in the terminal

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.